# Detecting changes in a set of values

Tags: c

I have a project where a program takes numerous integer values and detects changes between these values. Only one different value from others are accepted, and only one time. When an error has been identified, like 10 12 13 ..., the program needs to stop rightaway, not getting the other values.

```
e.g: 10 10 10 10 10 18 10 10 10
```

This is an accepted data entry, as 18 is used only one time and is the only different value.

```
e.g: 10 10 14 17 10 10 10 10
```

This is not an accepted data entry, as 3 different values were used.

```
e.g: 10 10 10 10 12 12 12 12 12
```

This is also not an accepted data entry, as 10 and 12 used multiple times.

I just couldn't create an algorithm for this, covering these 3 and probably more situations. Any idea(s)?

Comment: do an insertion sort that has a check to see if (1) already a duplicate of a specific value and (2) has there been a duplicate yet. As long as the insertion sort is adding unique values, keep processing. Once a non-unique value is found, set a flag so that if another non-unique value is found, stop processing.

Comment: How do you "take" the input? Is it stored in an array? Is it read from keyboard or a file without storing it? Is the first value always the reference value?

Comment: you get values from where? Still in array? reading them?

Comment: Values are being read from keyboard. There are no reference value sadly, if only that were the case.

Comment: does order of data important in the target array?

Comment: No, it's not important.

Comment: you could sort the array and check if first and second items are the same and if the last and one-before last are the same

Answer (score 0):

The simplest algorithm I could come up with involves counting the number of times you see the two distinct values. Assuming `input` is an array with size `input_size`, this function returns `0` when the sequence is changed too much and `1` if one or zero changes are detected:

```
int isvalidsequence(const int *input, int input_size)
{
    int item1, item2;
    int seen1 = 0, seen2 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < input_size; ++i)
    {
        int item = input[i];
        if (seen1 == 0)
        {
            item1 = item;
            ++seen1;
        }
        else if (item == item1)
        {
            ++seen1;
        }
        else if (seen2 == 0)
        {
            item2 = item;
            ++seen2;
        }
        else if (item == item2)
        {
            ++seen2;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

        /* Exit loop early if we've already seen both characters more than once */
        if (seen1 > 1 && seen2 > 1)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

It stores the first distinct item it sees and the second distinct item it sees and then starts counting how many times it sees each. If it then finds a third distinct item, then the sequence is changed too much. If it finds that both the first and the second distinct items have been seen more than once, then also the sequence has changed too much. Else, at least one of the two items has been seen 0 or 1 times, so the sequence is valid.

Comment: I had written the original comparing characters, while it should have been integers as in your case. Fixed the code/text to compare integers.

Comment: note that if array can be long it is possible to prevent re-checking all numbers by storing them (i.e. in statics variables) and just update stuff for new values. Of course it will need a "re-initialisation" command to restart with a new sequence of values.

Comment: @hexasoft It would be fun to extend this to a module when such functionality is required.